# Bootstrap v4 - Keep form-control items within it's parent - what is needed?

Tags: bootstrap-4

See example, the input and textarea are outside the container on the right; I want to keep them fully within container, on the right; I know it's the margin that's pushing it outside, how can I force the parent to retain it fully? (hmm maybe it's padding instead of margin? too late, I've already written the question)

Am I missing something in Bootstrap v4 usage. It should be something simple, I should not manually have to adjust the css to compensate for margins?

```css
html, body {
  background-color:lightgray;
}

section {
    background-color: lightpink;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

section .data-entry {
  background-color: steelblue;
  position:relative;
}

section .data-entry 
> input, textarea
{
    resize: none !important; /*important is used to override stackoverflow css */
    margin:10px !important;
}


section .data-entry 
> .btn-actions {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin:10px;
}

section .data-entry 
> .btn-actions > button {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- uses bootstrap 4 -->
<section class="comments container">
    <h4>some header</h4>

    <div class="data-entry form">
        <p>*explanatory note.</p>
        <input placeholder="Mandatory header" class="form-control" />
        <textarea rows="5" cols="80" placeholder="Mandatory text" class="form-control"></textarea>

        <div class="btn-actions">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Clear</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working solution I found:

1. Replaced **.data-entry** with **.form-group** and added `<form>` tag
2. introduced this in in the CSS file:

   `.form-group .form-control { width: -webkit-fill-available; }`
3. replaced margins from CSS file with **.m-2** bootstrap class.

***See fiddle, I think it is what you wanted.***

https://jsfiddle.net/Cornel777/2w1yfnkq/20/

HTML:

```
<head>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<!-- uses bootstrap 4 -->
<section class="comments container">
    <h4>some header</h4>

<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>*explanatory note.</p>
        <input placeholder="Mandatory header" class="form-control m-2" />
        <textarea rows="5" cols="80" placeholder="Mandatory text" class="form-control m-2"></textarea>

        <div class="btn-actions">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Clear</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </form>
    
</section>
```

And CSS:

```
 html, body {
      background-color:lightgray;
    }
    
    section {
        background-color: lightpink;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width:100%;
    }
    
     section .form-group {
      background-color: steelblue;
      position:relative;
    }
    
    .form-group .form-control {
      width: -webkit-fill-available;
    }

    section .form-group
    > .btn-actions {
        display:flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        margin:10px;
    }
    
    
    section .form-group 
    > .btn-actions > button {
        margin-left:10px;
    }
```

Comment: Ok. I will accept your answer because it may be a better standard BS4 way! But why are you adding a form tag, I don't really want a form tag, because I am not going to be doing any POST-ing of the form.

Comment: Habit, you could remove it without any issues.